# Integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos x}{x}\left(\int_0^x \frac{\sin t}{t}dt\right)^2dx=-\frac{7}{6}\zeta(3)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, special-functions

I am trying to prove this below.
$$
I:=\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos x}{x}\left(\int_0^x \frac{\sin t}{t}dt\right)^2dx=-\frac{7}{6}\zeta(3)
$$
where 
$$
\zeta(3)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3}.
$$
I am not sure how to work with the integral over $t$ because it is from $0$ to $x$.   If we can somehow write
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos x}{x} \left(\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin t}{t}dt-\int_x^\infty \frac{\sin t}{t}dt     \right)^2dx=\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos x}{x}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\int_x^\infty \frac{\sin t}{t}dt\right)^2dx.
$$
I do not want to use an asymptotic expansion on the integral over $t$ from $x$ to $\infty$, I am looking for exact results.  Note we can use $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin t}{t}dt=\int_0^\infty \mathcal{L}[\sin t(s)]ds=\frac{\pi}{2}.$  Other than this approach I am not really sure how to go about this.  Note by definition
$$
\int_0^x \frac{\sin t}{t}dt\equiv Si(x),
$$
but I'm not too sure what this definition can be used for in terms of a proof.  Also note
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos x}{x}dx \to \infty.
$$

Comment: As quick hint, exand the integrant of the inernal integral into series, seems to me that will do the job.

Comment: I'd have written $\zeta(3)$ rather than $\zeta_3$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Okay that is great to know thanks a lot.

Comment: Quick irrelevant question, why do people use $:=$?

Comment: See here for a nice solution:  http://integralsandseries.prophpbb.com/post1969.html?hilit=sine%20integral#p1969    scroll to the bottom thread

Comment: @Cody that link does not work for me.  Perhaps post the solution or do you have it as PDF? thanks

Comment: @Integrals Are you able to access the forum at all? http://integralsandseries.prophpbb.com/

Comment: @RandomVariable No that link doesn't work, nor am I familiar with that forum!  I only knew of this math stack one

Comment: It's a small forum that I often post to.  I'm not sure why you can't access it.

Comment: @RandomVariable I am also not sure...  Thanks.  Well if you post there it must be very good!  I like integral forums

Comment: @Integrals : May be that site's blocked in your country? Try entering the url in a web proxy.

Comment: I just clicked on the link and it worked fine. Besides that, I thought I would introduce you to a new forum.

Comment: @gar Yes that is clearly the case, you must be right...  I do not use web proxy.  Thanks though.

Comment: @Cody Thanks although I  cannot access the forum.  Perhaps you can post the solution here?  Thank you sir.

Comment: @Integrals : Okay.. I wish Shobhit himself to post it here since he's the one who answered there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's strange that you're unable to access that link. I do not understand that.

I accredit this to Shobit.

Anyway, what Shobit done was to write it as a triple integral.

$$I=\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\cos(x)\sin(xy)\sin(xz)}{xyz}dydzdx$$

$$I=1/4\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(x(y-z+1))+\cos(x(y-z-1))-\cos(x(y+z+1))-\cos(x(y+z-1))}{xyz}dxdydz$$

Now, use the known result:  $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(bx)-\cos(ax)}{x}dx=\log(a/b)$$

Using this, it can now be written in terms of a log:

$$I=1/4\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{yz}\log\left(\frac{(y+z+1)(y+z-1)}{(y-z+1)(y-z-1)}\right)dydz$$

Now, integrating this w.r.t y is where the dilogs come into play:

$$I=1/4\int_{0}^{1}\frac{Li_{2}(\frac{1}{z+1})+Li_{2}(\frac{1}{z-1})-Li_{2}(\frac{-1}{z+1})-Li_{2}(\frac{1}{1-z})}{z}dz$$

Maybe you can finish it now on your own. It is now a matter of known dilog integrals. This is the bulk of it. But, if you need more I can write the rest later.

Comment: Thanks.  This is fine to finish from here.  I didn't see the Frullani like integral at all.  And obviously writing it as a triple integral is very nice insight, I thought of neither.  +1

Comment: Thanks Integral.  If Shobit ever shows back up, please go ahead and give him a greenie because, afterall, it is his answer. I was just helping out because you could not access the link.

Comment: I would very much appreciate to be given more details on how to finalize the last four dilogarythm integrals
fjaclot

Comment: I am not familiar with this site and kndly ask clarification on how to finaoize the last four dilog integrals. fjaclot

Comment: May I have a hint on how to finalize the four dilog integrals. Thks. fjaclot